# I am not able to type more than a character at a single time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autofocus

This is the code of Notes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import NoteState from '../context/notes/NoteState'

export const NoteContext = React.createContext()

export default function About() {
  const host = "http://localhost:5000/notes"

  const notesInitial = []

  const [notes, setNotes] = React.useState(notesInitial);

  //get all notes 
  const getNotes = async () => {
    //API CALL
    const response = await fetch(`${host}/allnotes`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "auth-token": 'randomgibberish'
      }
    })
      const json = await response.json();
      console.log(json)
      setNotes(json)
    
    }



  //ADD NOTE
  const addNote = async (title, description, tag) => {
    //API CALL
    const response = await fetch(`${host}/addnote`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "auth-token": 'randomgibberish'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({title, description, tag})
    });
    const json = response.json()
    console.log(json);
    
    
    //Logic to Add the Note
    const note = 
    {
        "_id": "64073219511b4f062e42bb91d1",
        "user": "63fe0f8bbea2272fc98d6e2e",
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
        "tag": tag,
        "Date": "2021-09-03T14:20:09.668Z",
        __v: 0
      };
    setNotes(notes.concat(note))
    }

  //DELETE NOTE
  const deleteNote = async (id) => {
    //TODO API CALL
    //API CALL
    const response = await fetch(`${host}/deletenote/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "auth-token": 'randomgibberish'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({id})
    })
    const json =  response.json();
    console.log(json)

    //Logic to Delete the Note
    console.log("deleting the note with id" + id)
    const newNotes = notes.filter((note) => { return note._id !== id })
    setNotes(newNotes)
  }

  //EDIT NOTE
  const editNote = async (id, title, description, tag) => {
    //API CALL
    const response = await fetch(`${host}/updatenote/${id}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "auth-token": 'randomgibberish'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({title, description, tag})
    })
    const json =  response.json();
    console.log(json);


    //LOGIC TO EDIT THE NOTE
    for (let index = 0; index < notes.length; index++) {
      const element = notes[index];
      if (element._id === id) {
        element.title = title;
        element.description = description;
        element.tag = tag;
      }

    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <NoteContext.Provider value={{ notes, addNote , deleteNote, editNote, getNotes}}>
        <NoteState />
      </NoteContext.Provider>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is the code of NoteState.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar';
import { NoteContext} from '../../components/Notes'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Noteitem from '../../components/Noteitem'
import AddNote from './AddNote';
// import EditNote from '../../components/EditNote'

export default function NoteState() {
  const context = React.useContext(NoteContext);
  const {notes, getNotes} = context;

  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes()
    // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [])

  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [note, setNote] = useState({ etitle: "", edescription: "", etag: "" })
  
  const updateNote = (currentNote) => {
    setNote({etitle: currentNote.title, edescription: currentNote.description, etag:currentNote.tag})
    setModal(true)
  
  }


  const removenote = () => {
    setModal(false);
  }

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log("Updating the note...", note);
    e.preventDefault();
    removenote()
  }

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setNote({ ...note, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
  


    const MyModal = () => {

      useEffect(() => {
        document.body.style.overflowY="hidden";
        return () => {document.body.style.overflowY="scroll";}
      }, [])
      
        return (
          <>
            <div className="Modal">
                <h3>Edit Note</h3>
                <input id="etitle" type="text" name='etitle' value={note.etitle} onChange={onChange}/>
                <input id="edescription" type="text" name='edescription' value={note.edescription} onChange={onChange}/>
                <input id="etag" type="text" name='etag' value={note.etag} onChange={onChange}/>
                <div className='edit-btn-cont'>
                    <button id="edit-save" className="edit-btn" onClick={handleClick}>Save Changes</button>
                    <button className="edit-btn edit-btn-cancel " onClick={removenote} >Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div className='modal-container'></div>
            </>
        )
    }
  
  


  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <AddNote note={note}/>
      {modal && <MyModal/>}
      <h1 className='yournotes'>Your Notes</h1>
      <div className='notes-box'>
        {notes.map((note) => {
          return <Noteitem key={note._id} updateNote={updateNote} note={note}/>
        }
        )}
        </div>
    </>

  )
}
```

this is the code of AddNote.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { NoteContext } from '../../components/Notes'



export default function AddNote() {

  const context = React.useContext(NoteContext);
  const { addNote } = context;

  const [note, setNote] = useState({ title: "", description: "", tag: "default" })

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addNote(note.title, note.description, note.tag);
  }

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setNote({ ...note, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
  return (

    <div className="Notescontainer">
      <div className='addnoteContainer'>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <h1 style={{ color: "#8ae595", stroke: "none", textShadow: "#000 1px 1px 0.3px" }}>Add a</h1><h1 style={{ marginLeft: "9px", borderBottom: "3px dashed #8ae595", textShadow: "#8ae595 1px 1px 0.3px" }}> Note</h1>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name='title' id="Notes-textarea" style={{ marginBottom: "7px" }} placeholder='Enter Title' onChange={onChange} />
        <textarea name="description" id="Notes-textarea" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder='Enter the Note you want to add' onChange={onChange}></textarea>
        <div style={{ display: "flex", width: "100%", justifyContent: "center" }}>
          <input type="text" name='tag' className='Notes-input' placeholder='Enter the Tag' style={{ marginTop: "10px", width: "70%", marginRight: "4.55%", padding: "6px" }} onChange={onChange} />
          <button type="submit" className='signup-btn' onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )}
```

I think the problem is in MyModal Component which is in NoteState.js. I am only able to add a single character on the input element of the MyModal component after a character. It gets deselected and, to type a single character, again I have to click on the input element. And also i am not able to programatically run autoFocus on all of the 3 input elements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing `autoFocus={false}` to your modal component ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).